# The middle name of "Leslie B. Lamport"

Tags: tex-history

What is the middle name of "Leslie B. Lamport", the initial developer of the document preparation system, LaTeX?

I'm interested to know what is the middle name of his full name?

I know the middle name of "[Donald E. Knuth,](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/)" is: "Ervin".

Comment: Leslie Lamport didn't bother to mention a middle name on his phd thesis. Seems the *B.* is not at all important to him.

Comment: I suspect this is off-topic

Comment: @JosephWright I think it's not! The question is clearly related to LaTeX history. I found `B.` in his full name in some websites but I don't know really what is that stands for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leslie_Lamport

Comment: @Johannes_B, then how other people found _B._ in his middle name and put it on the websites, say Wikipedia?

Comment: The index of the TeXbook mentions “Lamport, Leslie B.”, which means that Leslie Lamport didn't reveal his middle name even to Donald Knuth, who's notoriously very fastidious in mentioning the full name of everybody he lists in indices (for instance, “Dull, Brutus Cyclops”).

Comment: Leslie Lamport remained very modest and willingly answers the question asked from his personal website (I have already written to him and he answered me): http://www.lamport.org

Comment: By the way, the "B. " Was introduced in 28th of May 2014 by a user with 5he ip 146.169.7.184

Comment: The same IP added "A. " to the name of Danielle Fong a few weeks later.

Answer (score 9):

Donald Knuth is notoriously fastidious about listing the full name of everyone he cites in his books. The index of the TeXbook has only a handful of names with abbreviations of names or middle names:

> Bach, P. D. Q.
>   Justus, Paul E.
>   Lamport, Leslie B.
>   Llanfair, P. G.

The entry “Watson, John Amish, M.D.” doesn't count, of course. Note that the reference to Llanfair is a joke, whereas [P. D. Q. Bach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P._D._Q._Bach) is a fictitious composer created by Peter Schickele. Paul E. Justus is the author of a [single paper on IEEE Transactions on Professional Communication](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6591969/).

Apparently, Leslie Lamport didn't disclose his middle name even to Knuth.

Comment: *The Art of Computer Programming* often cites Floyd (as "Robert W. Floyd" etc). In the index, the entry is given as "Floyd, Robert W" (no fullstop/period): the reason is that the W doesn't stand for anything (so the index has written out the full middle name), while the main text uses "W." which according to Knuth is an *abbreviation* of "W" :-) (See [here](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~zeilberg/KnuthMiddleNames.html).) The case of "Lamport, Leslie B." isn't like this, from which we can infer that it is not true (or at least DEK doesn't know for a fact) that the "B" stands for itself. :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR _Floyd had his middle name "Willoughby" legally changed to "W" but deemed abbreviating it as "W."_  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_W._Floyd#Notes. Why someone would want to have a middle name consisting of a single letter is beyond me.

Comment: @nadder Oh that's interesting, thanks. Maybe wanted to preserve the initial for continuity but otherwise get rid of that middle name.

Comment: @nadder -- The mathematician R H Bing had only initials.  On certain forms he would have had to enter his name as "R<only> H<only> Bing".  One of my former colleagues, himself a mathematician, always referred to him as "Ronly Honly".  (Why Bing's parents wished this on him is unknown.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Interesting, and funny :)